# QGIS Upgrading from Madeira (3.4) to Coruna (3.10)

Tags: qgis

Quick question!
I am running Madeira, which is my first and only installation of QGIS. Now that
Version Coruna is available.....

1. Should I bother to upgrade?
2. If upgrading, should I first **Uninstall** my
       QGIS Madeira? Or, does the installation routine of the Coruna version take
       care of that (e.g., only over-writing the files that have been
       altered from the one version to another)?
3. Will the new version of QGIS (Coruna) automatically find my Project files,
   and will it carry-over customized projections (coordinate systems)
   and so forth?

Comment: QGIS has two installers on their website, the standalone and the OSGeo4W. Which one did you use for 3.4?

Comment: The "OSGeo4W" is totally unfamiliar, so it must've been the 'Standalone'

Comment: As of 2020/01/24 and for the 3.10 version PSA from the QGIS blog : http://blog.qgis.org/2020/01/24/public-service-announcement-update-to-the-latest-point-release-now/ (in short they advice to update now to 3.10.2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. Should I bother to upgrade?

Definitely. QGIS is constantly under development. The latest release has several new features and I would definitely upgrade. General rule of thumbs:

a. Dont immediately update to a .0 release. So dont use 3.X.0, wait till 3.X.1 or 3.X.2 so the bugs are ironed out.

b. Dont uninstall the previous version that was working well for you until youve tested the new version. Sometimes your old scripts or plugins may not work on the latest release, its always worth checking before uninstalling a working version.

c. Dont upgrade if there a new version coming in the next few days. There is a timeline for releases her: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html
You can see that QGIS 3.10.2 is coming in within a couple of days. I would install that version, not 3.10.1.

> 2. If upgrading, should I first Uninstall my QGIS Madeira?

Always test to see that your custom tools are all working with the latest version before uninstalling the previous versions. You can have multiple installations of QGIS without issues. In my testing, 3.10.1 is a good release and I have upgraded to it and uninstalled all previous versions.

> 3. Will the new version of QGIS (Coruna) automatically find my Project files, and will it carry-over customized projections (coordinate systems) and so forth?

Yes, generally all your plugins, profiles and user data is saved separate to the installation directory. So you dont have to worry about losing data.

Comment: Thank you. That's a very complete answer....much appreciated. I upgraded to the final 'Madeira' (LTR / 'stable version') first, and will keep that version on my platform until Coruna proves itself.

Answer (score 6):

1) Definitly you should upgrade und you will like the new features, but you can have a look to the changelogs first: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/

2 and 3): You don't need to uninstall the 3.4 version, but you can if you want to do it. All your customized stuff (database connections, styles, wms services, last projects and so on) is saved in your profile folder and will be there after updating to a new version. I am running several versions on my computer (2.18, 3.4, 3.10, 3.11). If you want to start on scratch, just init a new profile. The profile folder you can access also over the menu shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: So.....Best to totally un-install First?

Comment: no, it is not necessary

Comment: Thanks to all...that seems to answer the questions.

Comment: Better to keep your old version until you know the new version works.

Comment: @Birdman if this answers your question, please accept it - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers